# Conditional UPDATE statement with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to update a column `Plan_Status` based on the value of another table `main`, column `Days_At_Step`.
 The following statements work, however, how would I structure this as a conditional statement? 
Or, is there another strategy that I could use?

I feel like there's a better way than using three identical statements with different WHERE conditions.

```
  UPDATE controlState 
  SET Plan_Status=1 
  FROM controlState JOIN main ON main.Cscc = controlState.Cscc 
  WHERE Days_At_Step < 2;

  UPDATE controlState 
  SET Plan_Status=2 
  FROM controlState JOIN main ON main.Cscc = controlState.Cscc 
  WHERE (Days_At_Step >= 2 OR Days_At_Step < 4);

  UPDATE controlState 
  SET Plan_Status=3 
  FROM controlState JOIN main ON main.Cscc = controlState.Cscc 
  WHERE Days_At_Step > 4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three `where` clauses cover all the possible values `Days_At_Step` could get, so you really don't need a `where` clause at all. Instead, you can move this logic to a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE controlState 
SET    Plan_Status = CASE WHEN Days_At_Step < 2 THEN 1 
                          WHEN (Days_At_Step >= 2 OR Days_At_Step < 4) THEN 2
                          ELSE 3
                     END
FROM   controlState 
JOIN   main ON main.Cscc = controlState.Cscc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can work:

```
UPDATE controlState 
SET Plan_Status = 
  CASE WHEN Days_At_Step < 2 THEN 1
       WHEN (Days_At_Step >= 2 OR Days_At_Step < 4) THEN 2
       WHEN Days_At_Step > 4 THEN 3 END
FROM controlState JOIN main ON   main.Cscc = controlState.Cscc
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UPDATE controlState 
SET Plan_Status = CASE 
                  WHEN Days_At_Step < 2 THEN 1
                  WHEN (Days_At_Step >= 2 OR Days_At_Step < 4) THEN 2
                  WHEN Days_At_Step > 4 THEN 3 END
FROM controlState JOIN main ON main.Cscc = controlState.Cscc
```